# How to disable check boxes on table using Material-UI from previous dates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I currently have a table with a date picker that you can select from to display people scheduled for the Date selected. I currently want to be able to disable the check boxes when it is not today's date.

I know you can disable check boxes to the table with

```
"selectableRows: "none"
```

What are some of the best ways to approach this?

Comment: What have you tried? Can you share a minimal code in codepen, jsfiddle?